# Python - QRCode error "No module named 'image'"

Tags: python, qr-code

I am trying to create an QRCode by using the 'qrcode' library.
However, when I try to make an image, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\qrcode\image\pil.py", line 6, in <module>
    from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
ImportError: No module named 'PIL'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Floris/Documents/GitHub/MiniProject-GroepV1L/TEST_QR.py", line 4, in <module>
    img = qrcode.make(string)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\qrcode\main.py", line 11, in make
    return qr.make_image()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\qrcode\main.py", line 256, in make_image
    from qrcode.image.pil import PilImage
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\qrcode\image\pil.py", line 8, in <module>
    import Image
ImportError: No module named 'Image'
```

The code I have right now is:

```
import qrcode

string = "This is a test string for StackOverflow"
img = qrcode.make(string)
```

Comment: You installed all the prerequisites, right?

Comment: Hey @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, I instaled the library "qrcode", but that's it,

Comment: dont just download modules from websites use pip to install qrcode so it installs dependencies for you

Comment: @DreadfulWeather Hello, thank you for replying. I tried to install PIL but apparently was outdated, so I installed "Pillow" instead. Now I don't get an error message. Great, right? How can I check whether it is actually generating an image...What is the easiest way to display an image?

Comment: Open it with some kind of picture wiever ?

Comment: I can't find an image file anywhere? As far as I know, it just keeps the image within the Python file. I don't think it saves a file anywhere...

Comment: try _pip freeze_ and see it PIL is installed in your python.   if not google instructions on using pip to install PIl, otherwise do some research on package managers.   I recommend Anaconda

Comment: @Joop, it says I have Pilow 3.0 installed. Which is correct, right? However, I still don't understand how to get an image to display.

Comment: from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/qrcode  looks like your library might need PIL.  DO not know details of these.   Hence the reason for a good package manager.   try pip install PIL

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to install Pillow:

```
pip install pillow
```

And probably some other dependencies.

You should have installed the *qrcode* package using pip so that the dependencies would have been installed.

Comment: I installed via Pip - Pillow wasn't included.

Comment: I had the same problem and I wonder why my import statement `import qrcode.image.pil` gives this error and then is resolved by installing `pillow`. If `pillow` is a package with this name, why can it be imported from `qrcode.image.pil`?

Answer (score 2):

For a standard install (which will include pillow for generating images), run:

`pip install qrcode[pil]`

([docs](https://github.com/lincolnloop/python-qrcode))

Answer (score 1):

Apparently after downloading the package with the pil command from readme:

```
pip3 install[pil]
```

I had to apply the quotations for the bash purposes in order to download it with PIL:

```
pip3 install"[pil]"
```

and because I was doing it after some time, I run upgrade just in case:

```
pip3 install"[pil]" -U
```

The **StyledPilImage** is neither in **qrcode** package neither in **PIL** package (I searched both of them). I don't see how creating those qr codes with nice, rounded dots would be possible now with **just** installing this with pip.

### Solution

In order to have those beautiful, rounded-corner qr codes with nice colours:

[image: Twitter]

You just need to have the code that you are looking form properly imported. Where from?

The [official repo](https://github.com/lincolnloop/python-qrcode/blob/master/qrcode/image/styles/colormasks.py) of course. Download it with e.g. git (or just copy the functions you need)

```
git clone https://github.com/lincolnloop/python-qrcode.git
```

and copy the qrcode folder from the downloaded repo to your pip packages folder.

I copied them to my **site-packages** folder which has the qrcode package:

```
lib/python3.7/site-packages/qrcode
```

to see where you have it run:

```
pip list -v
```

and it works like a charm.

The thing is that the README was changed for the repo but the [last verified tag](https://github.com/lincolnloop/python-qrcode/tags) on it was 6.1 which did not have styles. It needs to be updated cause current version that I am running (and works) is 7.1

@EDIT

It is updated now. Just run:

```
pip install PACKAGE_NAME -U
```

Comment: for those having ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qrcode.image.styles.moduledrawers.pil'; 'qrcode.image.styles.moduledrawers errors

 this should be the right answer. i installed and reinstall the qrcode and pil package and still doesn't fix it. as it turns out, the files above were not included in the pypi install